# Booting Debian ISO

Tags: debian, system-installation, preseed

Ive mastered enough of the preseeding feature of Debian OS to boot a installation CD without the need to enter anything. But I'd like to know now if it is possible to go further and just enter the CD for it to start installation : no boot option to enter, no type of installation to choose. Just put the CD and that it starts straight away, is it possible ? I could not find any documentation for this.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want a CD/USB with Debian preinstalled, like for a live boot? Or do you want a CD/USB with Debian on it that installes on the machine automatically?

Comment: A cd which installs Debian automatically.

Answer (score 2):

One needs to edit the isolinux/isolinux.cfg and set the timeout to 1 for example, and also set the default install accordingly.

Comment: Some of these scripts may help: https://github.com/dotzero/vagrant-debian-wheezy-64